# debugging xslt transformation which is invoked from java using eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xslt

Lets say, we have a input XML, which needs to be transformed into output XML(for the sake of discussion, let consider it as output HTML) using some XSL file, this transformation is triggered from java code using `javax.xml.transform.Transformer` and invoking its `Transformer.transform(Source xmlSource, Result outputTarget)` method.

My question is, In this situation is there any way to debug the XSL tranformation(I mean any facility where I can set break-point in XSL file as well as in Java class).

I know XSLT debugging is available in eclipse but that doesn't suffice above situation,I guess(since it only talk about input xml and xsl file, Anyway you can correct me If I am wrong)

Comment: I haven't used XSLT in Java enough to say one way or the other, but what if you used the debugger to capture the XML input and save it to a file, and then use Eclipse debugger to debug it. Is that process too troublesome?

Comment: Try this http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/xslt_debugger.html